# Expected specifier-qualifier-list - Why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, syntax

I've got an app I'm working on, its got 4 views so far that work fine, I've added another view (with .h & .m files) and now it wont compile.  I've copied the code from the other lines but cannot figure out the problem.

the error is on line    IBOutlet fifthViewController *fifthViewController;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class FirstViewController;
@class SecondViewController;
@class ThirdViewController;
@class ForthViewController;
@class fifthviewcontroller;

@interface MulipleViewsViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet FirstViewController *firstViewController;
    IBOutlet SecondViewController *secondViewController;
    IBOutlet ThirdViewController *thirdViewController;
    IBOutlet ForthViewController *forthViewController;
    IBOutlet fifthViewController *fifthViewController;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) FirstViewController *firstViewController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) SecondViewController *secondViewController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) ThirdViewController *thirdViewController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) ForthViewController *forthViewController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) fifthviewcontroller *FifthViewController;

-(IBAction) loadSecondView:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) loadThirdView:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) loadFirstView:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) loadForthView:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) loadFifthView:(id)sender;

-(void) clearView;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) fifthviewcontroller *FifthViewController;
```

it should be:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) Fifthviewcontroller *fifthViewController;
```

---

and of course

```
IBOutlet fifthViewController *fifthViewController;
```

should be:

```
IBOutlet FifthViewController *fifthViewController;
```

---

here too:

```
@class fifthviewcontroller;
```

should be

```
@class FifthViewcontroller;
```

Comment: Same goes for the IBOutlet: needs to be FifthViewController* rather than fifthViewController*.

Comment: I've tried changing them around from uppercase to lower case and vice versa but the IBOUTLET line still keeps erroring.

Comment: You should rename your fifthviewcontroller class name to Fifthviewcontroller it's common practice to capitalize class names.

Comment: thanks, managed to fix it, it also needed a capital V in View.

Comment: I'm now getting an error in the .M file, "no declaration of property fifthviewcontroller found in the interface.  the line in question is - @synthesize FifthViewController; I have included the .H file

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the class and property, you use `fifthviewcontroller` with no capitals, but when you declare the instance variable, you capitalize the V and C: `fifthViewController`. From the context, it appears that the capitalizations are a mistake and that line should be changed to `IBOutlet fifthviewcontroller *fifthViewController;`

In the future, when posting about errors, please indicate in the code which line the error occurs on.

Comment: The line is listed in the original msg, it states that its the IBOUTLET fifthviewcontroller line.